# display views3 output at page--mypage.tpl.php

Tags: theming

Using drupal7 views3 i created views(products) to display an image and relevant title of my content. I selected in products to display content as block not page. I created an overriding page template page--mypage.tpl.php, where i impose my own html-css layout. My question is, that i want to display the content of newproducts block at page--mypage.tpl.php:

[title] [image], [title2][image2], [title3][image3]

I have created the html/css in page--mypage.tpl.php for the above layout. Now, i don't know how to retrieve the produts output to populate the above layout. For example, I used , or content);?>, but i couldn't accomplish my objectives. Someone who knows this theming could let me figure out this issue please![my html/css layout][1]!

Answer (score 1):

[views_embed_view](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.module/function/views_embed_view/6) should help you.